# Add status to category product listing tab

Tags: adminhtml, category

When in categroy admin, products tab don't show their status in any way. 
How to add that kind of feature? What files should I edit?

I think solution could be either:

1. Add status field to listing header
2. Add tag like "[Disabled]" to the product name in listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the Category Product Grid block.
For this create a new module. Let's call it `Easylife_Catalog`.
You need the following files.
**`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Catalog.xml`** - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_category_tab_product>Easylife_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Tab_Product</catalog_category_tab_product>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php` - your new block

```
<?php
class Easylife_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Category_Tab_Product
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product {
    public function _preparePage() {
        $this->getCollection()->joinAttribute(
            'status',
            'catalog_product/status',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $this->_getStore()->getId()
        );
        return parent::_preparePage();
    }
    public function _prepareColumns(){
        $this->addColumnAfter('status', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
        ), 'sku');
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create the Custom category attribute.

1) The [atwix](http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/) provide you steps how to create the Category attribute via code.

2) The Extension is also available in [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attributes-manager-1.html).

Hope you got your answers.